# Why Sum in database query giving NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose I have a table named "Expense" and it has some month-wise expense which may contain some "NULL", now I want to check the yearly expenses in total with this below query:-

[image]

```
Select Sum(January) + Sum (February) ..... (I skipped the rest 10 months)
from Expense
```

This gives result as "NULL"

How can I avoid this situation? I think there are more convenient way to check the yearly sum

Comment: `SUM(IIF(Col IS NULL, 0, Col))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`coalesce`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp) [ *with 0 as the second argument* ] to replace nulls for all month columns, otherwise you can not get true results from aggregation of numeric values :

```
select sum(coalesce(January,0)+coalesce(February,0) ... )
  from Expense
```

Answer (score 4):

All arithmetic or logical operations involving NULL yield NULL. For example:

```
SELECT 1 + NULL -- NULL
```

You must convert NULL to zeros before you can `+` them:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(SUM(January), 0) +
    COALESCE(SUM(February) , 0) +
    ...
```

It is also possible to add the columns first and then calculate the sum:

```
SELECT SUM(
    COALESCE(January, 0) +
    COALESCE(February, 0) +
)
```

---

Be advised that (i) SUM skips NULL values (ii) returns NULL instead of 0 if all values are NULL:

```
SELECT SUM(a) FROM (VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (NULL)
) AS v(a) -- returns 3 instead of NULL
```

It will return NULL if *all* values encountered were NULL:

```
SELECT SUM(a) FROM (VALUES
    (CAST(NULL AS INT)),
    (NULL),
    (NULL)
) AS v(a) -- returns NULL instead of 0
```

Answer (score 2):

use coalesce function to convert null to 0 then use sum

```
Select Sum(coalesce(January,0)) + Sum (coalesce(February,0)) ..... (I skipped the rest 10 months)
from Expense
```

Answer (score 0):

Because null + value is always null and in your sample some months sums are null, you can avoid this by adding ISNULL

```
Select isnull(Sum(January),0) + 
    isnull(Sum(February),0) 
--..... (I skipped the rest 10 months)
from Expense
```

Alternatively you can use below way:

```
Select Sum(
    isnull(January,0) + 
    isnull(February,0) 
    )
--..... (I skipped the rest 10 months)
from Expense
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISNULL(SUM(January),0)`.

Answer (score 0):

That because you have `NULL` values, you can use `Case`, `Coalesce` or `IIF`:

```
Select SUM(IIF(Col IS NULL, 0, Col))

Select SUM(CASE WHEN Col IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Col END)

Select COALESCE(Sum(Col), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any arithmetic function will return null if there is at least one null value in the given column. That's why you should use functions like coalesce or isNull (MSSQL), NVL (Oracle).